# IronPython cannot import module "os"

Tags: .net, ironpython

my c# code:

```
//Create the ScriptRuntime
engine = Python.CreateEngine();
//Create the scope for the ScriptEngine
scope = engine.CreateScope();


string pyfile = "D:\\MyAddin\\test.py";
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(pyfile);
var rt = source.Execute(scope);
```

and my test.py:

```
import os
import sys
...
print("test")
...
```

I get no problem at build time, but at runtime VS give me a error "cannot import module "os"". Where is the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When hosting IronPython in your code, you'll need to add the libraries to your path.  Not all will be included by default.

You can add it through the engine:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
//paths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib"); // or you can add the CPython libs instead
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```

Or through your script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
import os
```

Comment: but python scripts will be installed in python path right ? not in iron python installation path