# Calling python script from c# program-error: No Module named xml.etree.cElementTree

Tags: c#, xml, python-2.7, parsing, ironpython

I have written a python script to parse a xml file. I'm calling this file from C# project. But when running a program I'm getting error: No Module named xml.etree.cElementTree.

```
Program.cs
-----------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using IronPython.Hosting;
using IronPython.Modules;

namespace RunExternalScript
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to execute the python script!");
            Console.ReadLine();

            var py = Python.CreateEngine();
            try
            {
                py.ExecuteFile("wg.py");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                   "Oops! We couldn't execute the script because of an exception: " + ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}



wg.py
-----


import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET 

tree = ET.parse('Wg.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
childrens = root.getchildren()


for p in root.findall('WGTemplate'):
        name = p.find('TemplateName').text
        # print(name)
        loc = p.find('Filename').text
        # print(loc)
        for p1 in p.findall('Product'):
            print("{:<50}{:<50}{:>50}".format(name, loc, p1.text))
```

Note: There is no folder or file with name 'xml'

Comment: does the script work when run in standalone?

Comment: Yes. It works well.Only challenge is when integrated with c#.

Comment: Does any standard library module work or is it isolated to etree? Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18000650/468244) to see how you need to provide the hosted python engine with info about the location of the standard runtime.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll

Additional information: cannot import cElementTree from xml.etree

Comment: The above exception will be thrown after following the link which you have posted above.

Comment: What I found is that for every module, it could be xml.dom.minidom/ xml.etree.cElementTree/xml.etree.ElementTree-getting same error - No module named xxxxxxx. I think it may be a reference issue..Not sure how to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

set your python path, to know your system path
in .py file just type

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and with this you will get your sys path and set those all path in

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine(); //For Engine to initiate the script
            List<string> pathes = engine.GetSearchPaths().ToList();
            pathes.AddRange(new[]
            {
             @"<add your all path here>"
             });
            engine.SetSearchPaths(pathes);
```

i hope my answer help you to solve your problem.